# What is the best way to move from the Microsoft stack to open source dynamic website development?

Tags: asp.net, open-source

I am more familiar with the Microsoft stack and I have some knowledge with ASP.NET and SQL.

What is the best open source platform to learn and create a dynamic website with, focusing on the back end?

Comment: It would be nice if Kiran could revise the question himself and make his intentions more clear so that we don't have this back and forth over what the question is actually pertaining to.

Comment: The original question was quite clear. He has a little knowledge of ASP and SQL Sever, so what would be a good Open Source tech for him to learn. I don't see the controversy.

Comment: Reopened.  I think the current revision is in agreement with the original intent of the question (as far as I can tell).  @Kiran: It's not 100% clear whether you are looking for an open source platform or a specific project to learn from, but I'm leaning toward platform.  Please clarify if this is not the case.

Answer (score 2):

[PHP](http://PHP.net) for the website development

[MySQL](http://mysql.com) (or [PostgreSQL](http://postgresql.org)) for the database backend.

All are open source.

Comment: You edited the question into reading something completely different while I was writing this. Obviously I was not the only person who read it this way.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as the "best open source". There are many good ones that'll suit different programming styles and personalities.

Some of the more popular couple of open source languages for web development today are:

- PHP
- Ruby
- Python

Some of the more popular couple of open source databases are:

- PostgreSQL
- MySQL

As they're free, give them a spin and see what you prefer.

Comment: Glad to know I wasn't the only one who read the question the same way.

Comment: @TheTXI - agreed and @ceejayoz gave my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start with the dasBlog. you can see more information about this project and a lot more [here](http://www.asp.net/community/projects/) and videos [here](http://www.asp.net/learn/)

Answer (score 0):

The two most popular open source webapp platforms at the moment are [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) and [Django](http://rubyonrails.org/). They are both awesome, and a joy to work with.